# mod_proxy security issues

Tags: apache-2.2, security, mod-proxy, hacking

A friend is asking me about mod_proxy modules ,

They have a server that was recently attacked using mod_proxy and after checking his logs he said he wasn't vulnerable to those attacks since they have a newer version ...

So to avoid any further attack he's asking if those modules are needed on the server :

```
mod_proxy.so
mod_proxy_connect.so
mod_proxy_ftp.so
mod_proxy_http.so
mod_proxy_ajp.so
mod_proxy_balancer.so
```

or he can remove them safely ...

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is mod_proxy in use?  Look for any directives in the config that start with the word `Proxy`; that'll tell you what will break if mod_proxy is disabled.

As far as the specific attacks and vulnerabilities, we would need to know the details around what the attack was.